# Windows 7 Does not Fit On Screen, Even Bios

Tags: windows

I have  a windows 7 netbook, And with the correct Graphics Drivers Installed. My Problem  here is I can't See almost Half of my Windows Dektop. I have tried to change resolution No luck.

I can Aceess the startmenu with Windows Key, But I am only Able to see, from , "Devices & Printers" And Above. I cant see the task bar.

This happens in the bios too, so the Windows related diagnostics may not be related.

Comment: If this is happening in the bios, it isn't Windows related.  It is most likely either a setting in the monitor itself, or a faulty connection.  What monitor / connection is it?  [edit] your answer with any additional info

Comment: Its a Laptop. A Netbook. S

Comment: Has it been connected to an external monitor at some point?

Comment: @Paul No. I don't Think So.

Comment: Has the screen been replaced? As said, it may be a faulty connection. I've seen before if you unplug a laptop screen and plug a smaller screen on whilst device is on then you get your symptoms. Restarting with the smaller screen will trigger the new size to be picked up. Check your connection.

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question [Computer always asks to delete files when selected & deletes any active text](http://superuser.com/q/827501). Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers)